# Sorting strings using qSort

Tags: c++, c, qsort

According to this [site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/), I have done the following program which sorts strings.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char list[5][4]={"dat","mai","lik","mar","ana"};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x;
    puts("sortirebamde:");
     for (x=0;x>sizeof(list)/sizeof(char);x++)
     printf("%s\n",list[x]);
      qsort(&list,(sizeof(list)/sizeof(char)),sizeof(list[0]),strcmp);
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the error I get

```
13 C:\Documents and Settings\LIBRARY\Desktop\string_sortireba.cpp invalid conversion from `int (*)(const char*, const char*)' to `int (*)(const void*, const void*)' 
13 C:\Documents and Settings\LIBRARY\Desktop\string_sortireba.cpp   initializing argument 4 of `void qsort(void*, size_t, size_t, int (*)(const void*, const void*))'
```

Please help

Comment: This is not a good way to sort strings in C, you should probably sort an array of char *, not a two-dimensional array with fixed length strings.

Comment: it should be: for (x=0;x<sizeof(list)/sizeof(char);x++)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please note: It is unusual to store C strings in two dimensional char arrays.  It's more normal to have `char *ary[]`, such as argv.  That type cannot be sorted directly using `qsort` and `strcmp`, because qsort will pass `char **` not `char *` to the comparison function.  This is good for efficiency, the pointers can be swapped instead of the whole strings.  The [Linux manpage for qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) has some good example code with a correct comparison function.

You can't pass `strcmp` directly to `qsort` as its comparison function because `qsort` expects to pass pointers to `void` where `strcmp` expects pointers to `const char`. Given the required similarity between pointers to `void` and pointers to `char`, you *could* probably do it with a cast (for your code), but the cleaner way would be to write a function that takes the right types:

```
int cmpstr(void const *a, void const *b) { 
    char const *aa = (char const *)a;
    char const *bb = (char const *)b;

    return strcmp(aa, bb);
}
```

Note, however, that in C++ you'd normally want to use `std::sort` instead of `qsort`, and probably use `std::string` instead of `char *`, which case the sorting gets a lot simpler (and generally faster as well).

Comment: This function will work for the question as posed, but that is not a good way to sort strings.  This will not work to sort an array of char *, as qsort will pass char ** to the function.

Comment: @SamWatkins: Let me get this straight. You're downvoting because I answered the question he asked, instead of telling him how to do something almost (but not quite) completely different from what he asked?

Comment: Ok, maybe that's unfair. I proposed an edit to your answer and will removed the downvote if the edit is accepted.  (can't remove it right now due to "the rules"
)

Comment: for completeness, the cast version version would be: (int (*)(const void*, const void *))strcmp), see the [working example](http://ideone.com/FzCgJE)

Answer (score 1):

The fourth argument of qsort takes 2 void* pointers as args.So you need to define a compare function for yours.
refer to this [link](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/c/qsort__sorting_array_of_strings__integers_and_structs.xml) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass strcmp directly to qsort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char list[5][4]={"dat","mai","lik","mar","ana"};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x;
    puts("unsorted:");
    for (x=0;x<sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]);x++)
        printf("%s\n",list[x]);

    qsort(list,sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]),sizeof(list[0]),strcmp);

    puts("sorted:");
    for (x=0;x<sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]);x++)
        printf("%s\n",list[x]);
//  system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

use C, not C++

Comment: Do not pass strcmp directly to qsort, in the normal case (sorting an array of char *) it will not work, and it's always a type violation.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond [why qsort fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757899/sorting-strings-using-qsort/3757917#3757917), don't use it in C++.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

char const* const raw_data[5] = {"dat", "mai", "lik", "mar", "ana"};

std::vector<std::string> data (raw_data, raw_data + 5);
// would rarely be a global

// see below for code that needs to go here

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  cout << "before: " << data << "\n";
  sort(data.begin(), data.end());
  cout << "after: " << data << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Boost has stream inserter overloads to output a vector directly, but here's one [simple version](http://bitbucket.org/kniht/scraps/src/tip/cpp/kniht/streamutil.hpp).  This goes into a header, rather than being copied and pasted continually:

```
template<class Stream, class Iter, class Ch>
void write_sequence(Stream& s, Iter begin, Iter end, Ch const* initial, Ch const* sep, Ch const* final) {
  if (initial) {
    s << initial;
  }
  if (begin != end) {
    s << *begin;
    ++begin;
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
      if (sep) {
        s << sep;
      }
      s << *begin;
    }
  }
  if (final) {
    s << final;
  }
}

template<class T, class A>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, std::vector<T,A> const& value) {
  write_sequence(s, value.begin(), value.end(), "[", ", ", "]");
  return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More C++-Style - nowadays - with static_cast:

```
int scmp(const void * s1, const void * s2)
{
    const char* _s1 = *static_cast<const char* const*>(s1);
    const char* _s2 = *static_cast<const char* const*>(s2);
    return strcmp(_s1, _s2);
}
```

And in main():

```
char *str_arr[] = { "one", "two", "three" };
qsort(str_arr, sizeof(str_array)/sizeof(char*), sizeof(char*), scmp);
```

Much easier is it with vector and std::sort.